# Conditionally Adding / Removing Joins in a SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure which takes into input two table types (each of which contain only one ID column). These are filters which need to be applied to the main query inside the stored procedure. I was doing it by joining the main query with these two table type parameters. Something like below:

```
SELECT 
  <cols> 
FROM 
  <table> t join @tableVar1 v1 on t.c1 = v1.c1 
            join @tableVar2 v2 on t.c2 = v2.c2
```

Now I am required to change the procedure such that if the table variable contains no rows it should return back the entire set. So if @tableVar1 has 0 rows I do not join the main query with it.

What I wanted to do and I am struggling with is having the same query conditionally not do the join if the variable has 0 rows. I can add if statements for each combination, but that would mean I have to write 4 queries. The query is complex I am afraid changes made afterwards might go out of sync.

So is it possible to do this in the same query with minimal performance impact? Appreciate your help.

Comment: try changing INNER JOIN to LEFT OUTER JOIN :
LEFT OUTER JOIN @tablevar1 v1 ON t.c1 = v1.c1

Comment: why don't you use two separate queries under an if-else? there is no performance impact that way and it will be cleaner.

Comment: @Jayachandran I am using separate queries currently, but the problem is with two variables there are 4 combinations, and likely there would be one more filter that would make it 8 combinations and it becomes a maintainence hell.

Comment: @Rishabh Can you please elaborate, I might be missing the point but I dont think Left Outer join would help. Note it needs to filter based on values in table variable.

Comment: @Rishabh I think I got your point. It should work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe -

instead of inner joins, I have used left joins and then all 4 conditions go into the where clause.

```
declare @countv1 int, @countv2 int
select @countv1 = COUNT(1) from @tableVar1
select @countv2 = COUNT(1) from @tableVar2

SELECT 
  <cols> 
FROM 
  <table> t 
    left join @tableVar1 v1 on t.c1 = v1.c1 
    left join @tableVar2 v2 on t.c2 = v2.c2
where 
    (@countv1=0 or v1.c1 is not null)
    and 
    (@countv2=0 or v2.c1 is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve conditional Join using [`Dynamic SQL Query`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) like

```
Declare @CntVar1 int
Declare @CntVar2 int
Declare @ExSQL nvarchar(max)

select @CntVar1 = COUNT(1) from @tableVar1
select @CntVar2 = COUNT(1) from @tableVar2

Set @ExSQL= 'Select <cols> FROM <table> t' 
 IF @CntVar1>=1
 Begin
    Set @ExSQL = @ExSQL + 'join @tableVar1 v1 on t.c1 = v1.c1'
 End 
  IF @CntVar2>=1
 Begin
    Set @ExSQL = @ExSQL +'join @tableVar2 v2 on t.c2 = v2.c2'
 End

Exec Sp_executeSQL @ExSQL
```

Comment: Generally you would want sql-server to keep your procedure's execution plan in cache. This speeds up the execution the next time. Therefore, you would want to avoid dynamic queries.

Comment: In the general case, we will not see significant performance degradation, when using dynamic queries. So that I had used it and also in the Question **Rahul** asked for Conditional Join

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility might be something like :

```
declare @t1 TABLE (id int)
declare @t2 TABLE (id int)

...

select * from dbtest1 d where 1 =
   (case when not exists(select * from @t1) then 1 
         when exists(select * from @t1 t1 where t1.id = d.id) then 1 end)
 AND 1 = 
    (case when not exists(select * from @t2) then 1 
         when exists(select * from @t2 t2 where t2.id = d.id) then 1 end)
```

You'd want to check query plans and do some timings in your specific case to check if performance was satisfactory.